# Cómo se encierra un if y un for si los tengo que usar juntos sin que me de error de sintaxis

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber cómo es la forma correcta de ubicar el **for** dentro el **if** o si es al contrario, ya que lo tengo ubicado así como en el ejemplo y no me funciona el codigo, me da error de **sintaxis** ¿qué hago?.

```js
function ejemplo() {

if (instrucciones) {

for (instrucciones) {

}

} else (instrucciones) {

}

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que tratas de conseguir como resultado?, a partir de ahí podemos encontrar la respuesta

Comment: El error de sintaxis ahí es por el paréntesis de la función que no está bien cerrado, tienes una llave en lugar de un paréntesis.
Como dice @Aprendiz, si supieramos a dónde deseas llegar sería excelente.

Comment: @Aprendiz si tiene, está junto al `else`

Answer (score 4):

Tal vez deberías indentar tu código para saber que es lo que esta pasando, mas allá de que no estas solicitando ayuda para ningún error en especifico, le doy cabida a tu duda porque efectivamente estas reproduciendo el error y ya que la cosa es como lo especificas: **Es un error de sintaxis** te dejo la [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript) para que le eches un ojo.

Esencialmente en JavaScript, la mayoría de las sentencias se escriben dentro de llaves `{}` (objetos), tanto en funciones, como en condicionales y bucles.

Pero para responder una de tus dudas, si tienes una condicional o un bucle sin importar el orden este tiene que ser jerárquico es decir, siempre escribir dentro de las llaves.

```
if (foo..) { // Abre if
  for (foo..) { // Abre for
  } // Cierra for 
} // Cierra if
```

Ahora, **el problema** esta en que no estas escribiendo bien la sintaxis de la condicional.

**Las condicionales tienen algunas formas de escribirse**:

**If/Else:**

Para sentenciar código que cumpla con la condición o las condiciones que están dentro del if, esto se utiliza para manipular el comportamiento del código según un caso único; y todo lo de mas que no cumpla con la condición pasara o se ejecutará else si existe:

```
if (condición) {

} else {

}
```

**If/ElseIf**:

Para sentenciar código que cumpla con la condición o las condiciones que están dentro de los if, esto se utiliza para manipular el comportamiento del código según casos específicos; y todo lo de mas que no cumpla con las condiciones pasara o se ejecutará else si existe:

```
if (condición) {

} else if (condición 2) {

} else {

}
```

**Si indentamos tu código podemos ver que** (reproducción del problema):

```js
var hey = Math.random() >= 0.5;
function ejemplo(bool) {

  if (bool) {

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
      console.log(bool)
    }

  } else (bool) { // <= Aqui esta el problema.
    console.log("La variable es " + bool)
  }

}

ejemplo(hey);
```

Estas escribiendo mal la sintaxis de la condicional, **por lo que la manera correcta sería** (ejecutar varias veces):

```js
var hey = Math.random() >= 0.5;
function ejemplo(bool) {

  if (bool) {

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
      console.log(bool)
    }

  } else {
    console.log("La variable es " + bool)
  }

}

ejemplo(hey);
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, lo del indentado... siempre es bueno indentar el código para que este sea mas legible, un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

Te Aparece error de sintaxis porque simplemente el **else{}** no posee paréntesis. Se supone que ese bloque de código se ejecuta cuando no cumple la condición del **if(){}**. No suele ser un error frecuente, pero es necesario saberlo ya que el *else* no posee nada que evaluar (dentro de su estrutura si, pero no en el mismo nivel).

Mas allá de ese problema tu código no tiene ningun error de sintaxis...